Mechanics/Statics: How to decide which statics problem can be modeled/solved in 2D or 3D? What are the steps to identify the dimension?
I am a first year mechanical engineering student. In statics we learn to solve/model different problems (free body diagram, sum of forces in $x/y$ etc...) in 2D and in 3D. But how to think about 2D? What does it even mean? I mean the world is 3D, so all the problems should be modeled and solved in 3D right? What does "2D particle/body equilibrium" mean? I know how to solve 2D problems as I was taught, what the steps are, but I have problem with the concept or with the understanding of it. The problem is, that those examples are already on the paper, I just have to solve them, so I don't see exactly where those 2D simplifications came from. What if I want to create a problem on my own (could be anything with different forces acting on a body example...)? How do I make the decision if I can simplify the problem from 3D to 2D? What are the steps to go through? And again vice-versa, so when can't I use 2D and have to work in 3D?

We use 2D or 3D space according to the motion of the body. Suppose that you have a particle moving along a line in a 3D space. Its position can be specified using 3 coordinates but if we orient our X,Y,Z axes such that particle moves along one of the axes, its motion can be described using only one coordinate. We need not use 3 coordinates in this case although we can if we want to make things complicated. similarly if particle moves only in one plane then 2 coordinates are enough to specify its motion.
Hope it helped
